# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote ...............CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

i have data in http://localhost:3000/edata

```
[{"_id":"598705ac8f79380367e0a7f2","name":"prasad","age":"28","gender":"male","phone":8790440944},{"_id":"598733508f79380367e0a7f8","name":"ravi","age":"27","gender":"male","phone":"9912881777"}
```

i want this data to be get when i run my client application i.e http://localhost:4200

app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import {TasksComponent} from "../tasks/tasks.component";
 import {TaskServices} from "./services/task.services";

 @NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, TasksComponent],
imports: [BrowserModule,HttpModule],
providers: [TaskServices],
bootstrap: [AppComponent,TasksComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

tasks.component.ts

```
 import {Component, enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
 import {TaskServices} from "../app/services/task.services";
 enableProdMode();
 @Component({
 selector: 'tasks',
 templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
 })
 export class TasksComponent {
 constructor(private taskServices:TaskServices){
 this.taskServices.getTasks()
       .subscribe(tasks =>{
        console.log(tasks);
      });
  }
  title = 'app';
 }
```

task.services.ts

```
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

 @Injectable()
 export class TaskServices{
  constructor(private http:Http){
 console.log('Task service initialized....');
  }
    getTasks(){
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/edata')
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

when i run application ,in the console i am getting the error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/edata. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

how to Fix the error.and how to get data from the other host...plz help me.

Comment: how to enable cors in my code ,u mean in app.js file or in which file?

Comment: If you are testing it on browser then add Allow-Control-Allow-Origin extension to browser

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If using **Node-server** add this in your server.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});
```

and Add Hearders in your http method

```
return this.http.get(
  'http://localhost:3000/edata',{
    headers: {'Content-Type', undefined} /** Use Content-type as your requirement undifined OR application/json**/
  }).map(res => res.json())
```

Comment: It is a little more complicated ... you can not use   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ==  '*'  if you need cookies you actually have to specify the real domain name.    For details see:  https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/outrageous-strange-cross-site-security/

Comment: Note: If you're using localhost, you may need to use your IP address instead!

Comment: I'm using rails. Do you know what the solution could be?