# Node js response produces "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, ajax

I tried to connect Node with a simple form using AJAX. I have two files.

- The first one is a html file with a textbox and a button.
- The second one is the node server which responds to the request.

My aim is to receive an id from the user (in the textbox) and pass it to the node server (using AJAX call) and the node server returns the id and the corresponding name in JSON format.

Below is my code.

```
The HTML File with AJAX call
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="guid" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Get" />
</body>

<script>
    $('#submit').click(function() {              
            var id=$('#guid').val();;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'OPTIONS',
                        contentType: 'application/JSON;  charset=utf-8',
                        url: 'http://localhost:3300/in/'+id,                        
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert("sucess");
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("failed");
                        },

                    });
        });
</script>
```

The error produced is

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

The second file is my node server file which is info.js

```
const expr = require('express');
const app = expr();
app.disable('etag');
app.use(expr.json());
var data=[
  {id:"1",name:"aaa"},
  {id:"2",name:"bbb"},
  {id:"3",name:"ccc"}
];
app.options('/in/:id', function(req, res){
  const result = data.find(d=>d.id===req.params.id);
  res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
  res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
app.listen(3300);
console.log("listening to port 3300");
```

In the above code I changed the method from "GET" to "OPTIONS" as the AJAX call uses OPTIONS as its request type. I have logged the JSON data on the Console and it returns a JSON Format for the requested id.

The screenshots are below.
[The original web page and in the XHR the error is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q0x2.jpg)

[image: The VS Code Editor showing the correct name returned in JSON format]

I tried passing the JSON response to https://jsonlint.com/  and validated it. It shows the response is a proper JSON format.
I still can't figure out where i made the mistake. I am a complete beginner to Node so please help me figure out the issue.

The sample input passed is 2. The node responds with the correct name "bbb" and the JSON response {"id":"2","name":"bbb"} is logged on to console. But when passed to the webpage the error is produced.

**Edit: I tried running it on Chrome, where the expected response is obtained and the response tab of the XHR shows the JSON data but the error method in the ajax call is executed. But when i tried running it on Firefox this error was produced.**

Comment: Have you looked at the "network" tab of your browser console?

Comment: @ScottSauyet yep i looked at the network tab of the browser console. Please check the first screenshot i have attached. It shows the browser console. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q0x2.jpg

Comment: I didn't do much. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the mistake. The entire issue was to due to Cross Origin Request. The issue was **"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing node js"** which was shown in the Console Tab itself. Finally added the piece of code from 
[Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote ...............CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611400/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot) 
answer to my code in the server program and now it works perfectly fine..

Thank you..

Comment: I was going to post a question about that, but was distracted by pets.  Best of luck.