# Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Network Error"

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, routes, axios

error:
`Unhandled promise rejection Error: "Network Error"`

my front-end vue application is running in `http://localhost:8080` and backend is running in in `http://localhost:8082`
I'm requesting get request from axios from vue file to the backend.

```
onSubmit(){
        return axios.get(`http://192.168.43.35:8082/auth/$(this.email)-$(this.password)`).then(function(response){console.log(response)}).catch(function(error){
            throw error;
            console.log(error);
        });
```

and here is my endpoint

```
app.get('/auth/:email-:password',cors(),(req,res)=>{
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  var dbo = db.db("leaveautomation");
  dbo.collection("letters").find({email:req.params.email, password:req.params.password},{ projection: { _id: 0, email: 1,} }).toArray(function(err, result) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.send({
    email: result,
    length: result.length
  });
  db.close();
});
  });})
```

what could be the reason for this error!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote ...............CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611400/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot)

Comment: yes!..that resolved one error!, now there's one more

Comment: Please make sue `http://192.168.43.35:8082` is started?

Comment: yes! I can see the response by typing out in the URL field of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Did you add origin headers to your middleware on server-side?

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept,X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: I used cors module, got the error. now tried it manually, still getting the same error